Issue while trying to configure rule on DebugDiag using a Performance Counter
I'm facing a issue (0xC0000BB8) where I can't activate a rule after configuring it on DebugDiag. My goal is to use the tool to generate a dump from my ASP.NET MVC application running on IIS, being triggered by high processor or memory usage.
Full error: "Error while activating a PerfTrigger Rule via the DbgSvc service. Could not create perf trigger for the counter path specified. PdhStatus - 0xC0000BB8".
Currently using RDP to access a cloud provider machine, host is a Windows Server 2022 Datacenter.
Attempts to fix the issue:

Checking if Debug Diagnostic Service is running (it was);
Checking Windows permissions (both on local policies and when running the application);
Configuring Performance Monitor to show the same Performance Counter (it worked).

I have also checked and when I select a Performance Counter in DebugDiag rule configuration, it sets the same path as Performance Monitor does.
I've done some research and there might be something to do with the system language (right now Windows is in Portuguese and DebugDiag is a English only tool). Seems like other people had issues acessing performance counter's paths on other scenarios, and that was fixed by changing system language, but thats off limits for me, so I'm looking for possible solutions and new things to try.
